# d3 line graph using all the same y values, plots line at the bottom

Tags: d3.js

This is best shown by looking at:

http://bl.ocks.org/3824854 (this is a fork of [bobmonteverde’s block #2070123](http://bl.ocks.org/2070123))

For some reason, when you deselect the "cosine wave", the sine wave (which I have hardcoded not to be a sine wave at all, but a straight line) plummets to the bottom.

Any idea what is going wrong here, or how I can make this draw correctly in the case where the data happens to have all the same y values?

Comment: See my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540007/draw-the-line-use-the-same-y-values-plots-line-at-the-bottom/).