# d3.js start count from 0 Y-Axis

Tags: d3.js, dns

I'm am new to d3.js and I'm building on Mike Bostocks' [grouped bar chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051): .

My dataset has negative values(on the y-axis), but my bars are counting from the bottom of the chart instead of the 0 y-axis.

I understand that this is a domain issue, but given that the code references keys and not the specific column, what changes can I make to let it start from the 0 y-axis?

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  return d;}, 
function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }));
  x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
  y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d3.min(keys, function(key) { return d[key]; }); }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { return d[key]; }); })]).nice();
```

[Current Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo3OA.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "I understand that this is a domain issue"?

Comment: Perhaps I interpreted the question wrongly but believe that this problem was similar to mine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540007/draw-the-line-use-the-same-y-values-plots-line-at-the-bottom?rq=1

but when I tried to follow the solution, it didn't solve my issue